# How to solve Scanner Permissions issues

Tags: 13.04, scanner

My computer previously ran Ubuntu 10.4.  After upgrading to 13.4, my Epson scanner no longer can be found by the system.  Following documentation, I find the following:

```
$ sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the 
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x046d/0x082b at 001:007: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
...
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.
...
```

If I instead run sudo sane-find-scanner, I get

```
$ sudo sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0131 [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:001:009
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.
```

So what do I do?  scanimage -L does nothing for me and I don't know what the "backend's manpage" might be.  It's seems likely that this is a permissions issue since the scanner can be found as root, but I don't know how to solve it.  Can someone help?

**Update:**
I had also tried simple-scan and xsane.  Neither of them could find the scanner.  That was what led me to try sane-find-scanner.

Comment: Have you tried using another program? Perhaps `Simple Scan` or `gscan2pdf` just to see if you can get the scanner working at all?

For what it's worth, `sane-find-scanner` doesn't find my networked scanner, but `xsane` does.

Comment: see update above.  Yes, I had tried simple-scan and xsane

Comment: Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SANE%20-%20Installing%20a%20scanner%20that%20isn't%20auto-detected`

Comment: Thanks: Hmm, yes, wow, my scanner, the Epson Perfection V-300 Photo is NOT supported.  So how did it work with Ubuntu 10.04? Oh wait, it's all coming back to me:  "Perfection V300 Photo USB 0x04b8/0x0131 Unsupported supported by the epkowa backend plus non-free interpreter".  I remember now, I had to download some drivers from Epson.  Then everything worked without me having to change anything else, mess with udev, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My scanner(Epson Perfection V-300 Photo is NOT supported). So how did it ever work with Ubuntu 10.04? "Perfection V300 Photo    USB 0x04b8/0x0131 Unsupported   supported by the epkowa backend plus non-free interpreter".  Thanks to Marc for giving me [a place to look](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SANE%20-%20Installing%20a%20scanner%20that%20isn%27t%20auto-detected), the [first step there](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html) got me this information, which brought back the memories of what I had to do to get this to work with Ubuntu 10.04.  I downloaded the drivers and everything just worked.

I would say that the error message in sane-find-scanner is less helpful than it easily might be.

Instead of just

```
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.
```

they could have easily included a link to http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html and saved me hours of wasted time investigating.